# Udev: using result in comparision

Tags: linux, udev

Could anybody give a hint why this works?

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM="/bin/echo -n 12345", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="12345", RUN+="/path/to/some/script.sh %k %c $env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

And this does not?

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM="/bin/echo -n 12345", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="%c", RUN+="/path/to/some/script.sh %k %c $env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check that you are providing a `$result` to be substituted where you have specified `%c`. From **man udev**:

```
$result, %c
    The string returned by the external program requested with PROGRAM.
    A single part of the string, separated by a space character, may be
    selected by specifying the part number as an attribute: "%c{N}". If
    the number is followed by the "+" character, this part plus all
    remaining parts of the result string are substituted: "%c{N+}".
```

If you are not providing the proper `$result`, then there is your problem.

Comment: Hi David, I have checked the $result and it is passing to the script as expected and echo $2 inside the script prints "12345". I guess comparison ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="%c" performs before PROGRAM is executed but it seems to be a bug for me or I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I stumbled over a similar issue, only the other way around. The problem might be a mismatch between what you see in RUN and what happens during the comparison. And the reason for it is this beautiful gem (from man udev):

> The NAME, SYMLINK, PROGRAM, OWNER, GROUP, MODE and RUN fields support simple printf-like string substitutions. The RUN format chars gets applied **after all rules have been processed**, right before the program is executed. It allows the use of device properties set by earlier matching rules. For all other fields, substitutions are applied while the individual rule is being processed.

Another rule perhaps has changed your %c later on while during your comparison it holds another value. I don't think that the comparison is done before PROGRAM.

I'd suggest to use `udevadm test` in such cases.